# How to calculate fractions within parts of a cast dataframe?

Tags: r, aggregation

As a result of melting and subsequent casting`[1]` a dataset I obtained the following array(?) (`sumStats.c`):

```
, , group2 = G2_1, variable = area

            group1
group3        G1_1      G1_2     G1_3       G1_4
   G3_1      0.000     0.000     0.00      0.000
   G3_2      0.000     0.000     0.00      0.000
   G3_3      0.000     0.000     0.00      0.000
   G3_4      0.000     0.000     0.00      0.000
   G3_5      0.000     0.000     0.00      0.000
   G3_6      0.000     0.000     0.00      0.000
   G3_7      0.000     0.000 26336.99  85236.488
   G3_8      0.000  4999.235 87935.73 360062.128
   G3_9      0.000     0.000     0.00      0.000
   G3_10  7853.982 18538.285 49744.29 134180.428
   G3_11     0.000     0.000     0.00   8830.825
   G3_12     0.000     0.000     0.00      0.000


, , grou2 = G2_2, variable = area

         group1
group3         G1_1     G1_2      G1_3      G1_4
   G3_1       0.000     0.00      0.00      0.00
   G3_2       0.000     0.00      0.00      0.00
   G3_3       0.000     0.00      0.00      0.00
   G3_4       0.000     0.00      0.00      0.00
   G3_5       0.000     0.00      0.00      0.00
   G3_6       0.000     0.00      0.00  51772.66
   G3_7       0.000     0.00      0.00      0.00
   G3_8    7853.982 22086.38 140874.76 523373.88
   G3_9       0.000     0.00      0.00      0.00
   G3_10      0.000  1415.79  23325.94  13407.49
   G3_11      0.000     0.00      0.00      0.00
   G3_12      0.000     0.00      0.00      0.00


, , group2 = G2_3, variable = area

          group1
group3          G1_1      G1_2       G1_3        G1_4
   G3_1       0.0000     0.000      0.000      0.0000
   G3_2       0.0000     0.000      0.000      0.0000
   G3_3       0.0000     0.000      0.000     93.2632
   G3_4       0.0000     0.000      0.000      0.0000
   G3_5       0.0000     0.000      0.000  46353.3814
   G3_6       0.0000     0.000      0.000      0.0000
   G3_7       0.0000     0.000      0.000      0.0000
   G3_8    7390.0570 16851.829 101013.680 232666.8839
   G3_9       0.0000  2541.574   6397.271  87825.7232
   G3_10      0.0000     0.000      0.000      0.0000
   G3_11    436.9895  4118.440  56572.140 173866.7915
   G3_12      0.0000     0.000      0.000  47924.5494
```

Now I need to get the *fraction* of the variable (`area`) within each `group2` relative to the total of each `group1` across `group3`. So for example, G2_1 (`group2`) has 100% of G3_10 (`group3`) in G1_1 (`group1`), G1_2 (`group1`) has 21.24 % of G3_8 and 78.76 % of G3_10, and so forth. Once the percentages have been calculated for each column of `group1` I think that I can `melt()` the resulting arrays to get the dataframe needed for further analysis.

I feel that `ddply()` would be helpful here but as I have a hard time understanding how to use it for the task at hand, I would appreciate if someone could help out.

```
[1]
sumStats.m <- melt(sumStats, id=c("group1", "group2", "group3"), "area")
sumStats.c <- cast(sumStats.m, group3 ~ group1 ~ group2 ~ variable, sum)
```

Comment: So each row will sum to 100%?

Comment: Sorry, @James, I missed your question here! Anyway, I accepted your answer as it worked with a slight modification for the right margins.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
prop.table(sumstats.c,margin=c(1,3))
```

eg:

```
x<-xtabs(~cyl+vs+am,mtcars)
x
, , am = 0

   vs
cyl  0  1
  4  0  3
  6  0  4
  8 12  0

, , am = 1

   vs
cyl  0  1
  4  1  7
  6  3  0
  8  2  0

prop.table(x,margin=c(1,3))
, , am = 0

   vs
cyl     0     1
  4 0.000 1.000
  6 0.000 1.000
  8 1.000 0.000

, , am = 1

   vs
cyl     0     1
  4 0.125 0.875
  6 1.000 0.000
  8 1.000 0.000
```

Comment: Thank you for the pointer @James! One thing -- the `margin` argument needs to be `c(2,3)` to calculate column proportions.